# Input type number in angular generates error even if ng-show is hidden for that input (same ng-model)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code generates the error below, even if the element with type="number" is hidden by ng-show;
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt

Angular 1.4

in Controller:

```
this.obj = {
a: {type:'string',value:'str'},
b: {type:'number',value:2}
}
this.selected = 'a';
```

in Template

```
<span ng-show="ctrl.obj[selected]=='number'"><input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.model" /></span>

<span ng-show="ctrl.obj[selected]=='string'"><input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.model" /></span>
```

When I input text within the "text" type field, I still get an error in the console. How to fix it? `Error: [ngModel:numfmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ngModel/numfmt?p0=3`

Comment: It's fairly easy, both inputs use same model and both are in DOM all the time, when you put anything in the `text` type the number input tries to format and validate input but it's string. Either try `ng-if` or use different model for both

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever try ng-if instead?

```
<span ng-if="ctrl.obj[selected]=='number'"><input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.model" /></span>
<span ng-if="ctrl.obj[selected]=='string'"><input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.model" /></span>
```

Comment: You could extend the answer a bit? As for now it's very laconic and clearly the OP is missing some basic knowledge on angularjs/DOM

Comment: "ng-show" just hide and show the element and the element is still render, when using "ng-if" the element would be removed or don't exist in the DOM when false.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-show` will just show or hide the content, but render the content anyway, which will cause an error when assigning a string to a number. Use `ng-if` instead!